# VNC with Windows 7

Tags: software-recommendation, windows-7, vnc

I want remote desktop access to a Windows 7 Home Premium machine, but Home Premium does not have RDP server support. What are my options to set up a VNC server on Windows for best remote desktop experience from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different types of VNC available for Windows. Your best bet is to look for ones that work on all O/S's and use that one. The two I can think of off the top of my head are TightVNC and RealVNC. Give those a try and see what happens.

RealVNC: http://www.realvnc.com/products/download.html
TightVNC: http://www.tightvnc.com/

Personally I preferred using UltraVNC (back when Windows was my default system), however I had issues with it a few years back when I was slowly starting to make Ubuntu my default system... It didn't like me trying to access it from Ubuntu back then. Not sure if this is still the case, but you could give that a go too.

Answer (score 0):

I am reviewing this as part of askubuntu clean up. I would add another option, FreeNX.

FreeNX is the (Linux) open source server/client for the NX server

http://nomachine.com/

Install the NX server on windows, use the FreeNX client on Ubuntu.

FreeNX has the advantages of

1. Much better performance.
2. Increased security (NX connections are encrypted).